# python Format option with a condition to keep extra value

Tags: python

I have to create a table dynimically in sqllite with `colums=['col1,'col2','col3']`
so I am using:

```
create_query = "create table if not exists myTable1 ({0})".format(" text,".join(columns))
print(create_query)
```

This works.

But I have to keep "primary key" for a 3nd entry in List (or)1st entry in a List.

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 primary key ,col2,col3);
```

Is there any condition option we can use.
Basically I dont wan just the entries but want to add primary key also.
I tried different combinations with no luck

Comment: Do u mean that if there are less than 3 entries assign primary key to the first column and if there are more 3 assign to the 3rd column?

Comment: no. I want to addto a colum what ever I want. for now you can take column1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, The best way would be to add an inline for loop with an if condition to cycle through the values. To this we can add a variable `column_no` that will store the index of the column value to use as a primary key.
Here's what the resultant code would look like:

```
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
column_no = 0
create_query = "create table if not exists myTable1 ({0})".format(' text, '.join(val+(" primary key" if i==column_no else "") for (i, val) in enumerate(columns)))
print(create_query)
```